# How to fix controls in static methods - Visual basic c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, methods, static

Pretty new to visual basic and c#, and I know there are other questions almost identical to this but I cannot get their solutions to work.

I understand that in static methods you cannot have controls, but I cannot find (or more likely understand and implement) a solution.

Class of frmMain, this is the method that needs to be called. flpMain is a flow layout panel in frmMain. namebuttons() needs to be called from a class called frmUser.

```
public static void nameButtons() {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (Button b in flpMain.Controls) {
            b.Text = "Click to add a player";
            if (i < 37 && frmUser.Users.Length >= i + 1) {
                b.Text = frmUser.Users[i];
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Please help guys, I have been stuck on this all day. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Why do you need to make the method `static`?

Comment: Remove static keyword if you don't want to use this method from outside the class or otherwise if you really need it place your control in static class then you will able to call it

Comment: I am calling it from another class, if you know another way to do this I'm all ears.

Comment: I tried storing the control in a static variable, but the same issue occured.

Comment: *"I understand that in static methods you cannot have controls"*. Obviously you don't understand because that's simply not true. A `static` method is a member of the class rather than a member of an instance of the class, which means that you cannot refer to the current instance in a `static` method, which means that you cannot refer to controls on the current form in a `static` method.

Comment: The solution to your problem is to NOT declare the method `static` and then call it on the form instance that you want affect. People do just that all the time. This sounds rather like an XY problem, i.e. your actual issue is how to refer to the form you want to call the method on.

Comment: Ok, could you please show me how?

Comment: If `frmMain` is creating `frmUsers` then the most proper way to achieve your aim is probably for `frmUsers` to raise an event that `frmMain` can handle. The data required in `frmMain` can either be retrieved from one or more properties of `frmUsers` or else exposed via the `e` parameter of the event handler. A less proper alternative would be for `frmUsers` to have a reference to `frmMain` that was passed in when it was created, which can then be used to call an instance method of that form.

Comment: You might benefit from reading [this](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2013/10/managing-data-among-multiple-forms-part.html).

Comment: Remove static. Then In class `frmUser`, create a property `public frmMain MainForm { get; set; }`. When you create the `frmUser` in `frmMain` do it like this: `var userForm = new frmUser(); userForm.MainForm = this;` Now in the `frmUser` you have access to everything public in `frmMain`. For example, in `frmUser` you can do this: `MainForm.nameButtons()`.

Comment: Thank you both jmcilhinney and CodingYoshi! I used CodingYoshi's solution, and it works, but I will read through the link you provided jmcihinney and make sure I understand it. CodingYoshi could you please explain how your code works/provide me an article that explains it? Thanks so much guys!